# How to fix: TypeError: Can only add LpConstraintVar, LpConstraint, LpAffineExpression or True objects

Tags: python, pulp

I'm trying to create an LP using PuLP. The decision variables are generated by counting the rows of an .csv and adding one for every row. When i want to create my objective function, it gives back an TypeError.

```py
optimale_bestellmenge = ""
for rownum, row in data.iterrows():
    for i, schedule in enumerate(decision_variables):
        if rownum == i:
            formula = sqrt(2 * row['Kosten'] *row['bedarf'] / row['hkosten'])
            optimale_bestellmenge += formula

prob += optimale_bestellmenge
print ("Zielfunktion: " + str(optimale_bestellmenge))
```

I do know what a TypeError is in general, but I'm not able to figure out, how and which Type I should convert the formula to. This is the complete error:

```py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/T/Desktop/optimizer/eoq.py", line 62, in <module>
    optimales_eoq_modell(budget)
  File "C:/Users/T/Desktop/optimizer/eoq.py", line 37, in optimales_eoq_modell
    prob += optimale_bestellmenge
  File "C:\Users\T\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\pulp\pulp.py", line 1358, in __iadd__
    raise TypeError("Can only add LpConstraintVar, LpConstraint, LpAffineExpression or True objects")
TypeError: can only concatenate str (not "float") to str
```

I've already tried to convert the formula with a str()-function, but then the TypeError only changes to:

```py
TypeError: Can only add LpConstraintVar, LpConstraint, LpAffineExpression or True objects
```

Comment: I think the first usage of  "prob" is str. You should look there.

Comment: Sorry but your tip does not help me further. Can you specify it?

Comment: Using print(type(...)), debug your code. You can find which one is str and float.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a string:

```
optimale_bestellmenge = ""
```

This is a float:

```
formula = sqrt(2 * row['Kosten'] *row['bedarf'] / row['hkosten'])
```

This is you trying to add a float to a string:

```
optimale_bestellmenge += formula
```

If you just want the `formula` number to appear at the end of your `optimale_bestellmenge` string, do this:

```
optimale_bestellmenge += str(formula)
```

If you want to keep adding the number in `formula` to `optimale_bestellmenge`, change the definition of `optimale_bestellmenge` to be a float or int:

```
optimale_bestellmenge = 0
```